# jQuery Access Object Value

Tags: jquery

Hi guys can you please show me how to access the content inside the audioCollection object?

I am using the Echonest jQuery plugin with jQuery Templates

https://github.com/Rodeoclash/Echonest-jQuery-Plugin/blob/master/scripts/echonest.js

I went on firebug and typed `console.log(audioCollection)` and I am getting `ReferenceError: audioCollection is not defined`. Not sure if I am doing it right.

```
echonest.artist(artist).audio( function(audioCollection) {

$('#blog-page').find('.post').append( audioCollection.to_html('<p class="song-url" style="display:none;">${url}</p>') ); 
//appends url variable to html inside of audioCollection

var testing = audioCollection;  //returns [Object object]
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where exactly did you put `console.log(audioCollection)` ?

Comment: Are you using some plugin? If yes, which one? `audio` is not a standard jQuery function. You have to provide more information.

Comment: `audioCollection` only exists in the scope of its enclosing function. That's why you can't get its value from the global scope with Firebug.

Comment: Thank you Frederic! Felix I have updated the question with a link to the plugin I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm Not familiar with the object, but you can try to use my `dump()` function to see what's in it..

```
echonest.artist(artist).audio( function(audioCollection) {

    $('#blog-page').find('.post').append( audioCollection.to_html('<p class="song-url" style="display:none;">${url}</p>') ); 
    //appends url variable to html inside of audioCollection

    var testing = audioCollection;  //returns [Object object]
    alert(dump(testing));        
});

function dump(arr,level) {
    var dumped_text = "";
    if(!level) level = 0;

    //The padding given at the beginning of the line.
    var level_padding = "";
    for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++) level_padding += "    ";

    if(typeof(arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects 
        for(var item in arr) {
            var value = arr[item];

            if(typeof(value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
                dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' ...\n";
                dumped_text += dump(value,level+1);
            } else {
                dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => \"" + value + "\"\n";
            }
        }
    } else { //Stings/Chars/Numbers etc.
        dumped_text = "===>"+arr+"<===("+typeof(arr)+")";
    }
    return dumped_text;
}
```

**UPDATE**

to access your values, you can do something like this

```
var songs = testing.audio;
for (var x=0; x<songs.length; x++){
    alert(songs[x].title);
}
```

Comment: Hi it returned this: http://sharepaste.com/p/iyKbGL I would like to know how to access the values. I would appreciate anything to read on the subject

Answer (score 1):

I you only want a raw view of the object, I'd suggest the widely used [JSON.stringify()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480393/alternatives-of-json-stringify-in-javascript):

```
echonest.artist(artist).audio(function(audioCollection) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(audioCollection));

    // Appends url variable to html inside of audioCollection.
    $('#blog-page').find('.post').append(audioCollection.to_html(
        '<p class="song-url" style="display:none;">${url}</p>')); 
});
```