# Using jQuery to send a POST; server thinks GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get

Here is my javascript:

```
function sendAttack(attacker,defender,hpChange){
    USER_LAST_TIMESTAMP = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0);
    var attack = new Attack(TURN_ID,attacker,defender,hpChange);
    attack.action_sequence = ACTION_QUEUE;
    var attackJSON = JSON.stringify(attack);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlLeader + "attacks.json",
        data: attackJSON,
        success: function(data){
            ACTION_QUEUE++;
        }
    })  
}
```

In `setup.js` loaded prior to the above:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    accepts: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

This is what the server receives when I call that function:

```
2012-04-26T03:57:44+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/attacks.json?callback=jQuery17103089843031743851_1335412646794&{%22attacker%22:2,%22defender%22:3,%22hp_change%22:6.799999999999997,%22action_sequence%22:0}&_=1335412659141" for 167.206.19.130 at 2012-04-26 03:57:44 +0000
```

Not the "GET".  What's going on here?

Comment: First, have you tried to use different data as part of your post? Hard code a value, like data: "test=ing" or data: { test: 'ing'}. Second, are you using json2.js to enable "JSON.stringify" for browsers that don't natively support it? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480393/alternatives-of-json-stringify-in-javascript)

Comment: You are omitting the `dataType` parameter in your request; jQuery may be changing your request type for you.

Comment: dataType is for the return value. It would be more likely if a "contentType" was specified to impact sending data to the server. Are you changing the jQuery AJAX defaults anywhere?

Comment: It seems you are sending JSON to the server in which case you need to set processData to false and set the appropriate Content-Type else JQuery tries to convert the data into  application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME type.

Comment: Default type is "GET". Try to complete jQuery.ajax function with semi-colon (;) and then check it once. There may be a problem with syntax on browsers.

Comment: Just for debugging info, what would happen if you rewrote the ajax call using the $.post() method instead of the $.ajax() method? Does the server still receive it as a GET?

Answer (score 2):

maybe [this forum post at jquery.com](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/post-query-with-jquery-ajax-and-jsonp-datatype) describes your problem:

> Cross-domain JSONP requests are created by using a dynamic script tag, so they can only use a GET method.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this block of jQuery code is responsible:

```
// Handle cache's special case and global
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter( "script", function( s ) {
    if ( s.cache === undefined ) {
        s.cache = false;
    }
    if ( s.crossDomain ) {
        s.type = "GET";
        s.global = false;
    }
});
```

i.e. a cross-domain script request (as used by JSONP) gets its `type:` field reset to `GET`.

This is because JSONP doesn't use `XMLHTTPRequest` at all, it fakes up a `<script>` tag and then your browser creates its own `GET` request to retrieve that resource.