# onclick="doSomething([object Object])" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, onclick, syntax-error

`var params = {a:1,b:2};
 var str = '<a href="#" onclick="doSomething('+params+')">aaaa</a>';
 document.write(str);`

when I click the `<a>` on the page,it throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".I can't understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason is that when you use string concatenation, `params` is casted to string, as result you get something like `[object Object]` in parenthesis.

You should better put params as `var params = '{a:1,b:2}';`.

**Upd.**
As suggested in comments, another viable approach is using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer-new.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var params = {a:1,b:2};
var str = '<a href="#" onclick="doSomething('
    + JSON.stringify(params)
    + ')">aaaa</a>';
document.write(str);
```

Please, pay attention that `JSON.stringify` may not be supported by older browsers and you'll need to include [additional libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480393/alternatives-of-json-stringify-in-javascript) to make them work.

Comment: I would add to this that if you cannot hard code the object like is shown in the example and actually need to convert an object to string, you can use `JSON.stringify(params)` to ensure the correct format.

Comment: note that, according to http://escape.alf.nu, `%22` gets parsed to `"`, so passing this value to `href` instead of `onclick` will lead to XSS vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

[object Object] is the string representation of any JavaScript object. In your scenario you have `params` concatenated with a string, which will cast any variable type to a string.

Answer (score 0):

The in your case `str` looks like this:
`<a href="#" onclick="doSomething([object Object])">aaaa</a>`

As you can see, that is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Li0liQ is quite Ok. When you clicking on that link you can find `doSomething[object Object]`

This is only object required .You are not writing the params into `document`. Casting Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue.
Reason for the issue: params is converted to string 'object Object' when html is rendered.

The problem can be sorted out in two ways:

Approach 1: add a click handler to the js code. Refer [add click handler](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Approach 2: Say I want to pass a JSON object named 'params' to the onclick function. As I need a very few attributes of the 'params' object, instead of adding a new handler as in 1st approach, I would rather just pass those specific parameters as below:

```
'<a href="#" onclick="doSomething(\'' + params['attribute1'] + '\'\, \'' +params['attribute2'] + '\'\)">aaa</a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick='setInputForUpdate(${JSON.stringify(data)})' data-bs-toggle="modal"