# How can I pass json to function?

Tags: javascript, json

I have test.js:

```
const header = document.querySelector('header');
const section = document.querySelector('section');
let requestURL = 'list';
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();

let mainContent = '', main = document.getElementById ("main");

request.onload = function() {
  const students = request.response;
  students.forEach(student => {
  output(student);
  mainContent += '<button id="edit" onclick="input(' + JSON.stringify(student) + ')">Id: ' + student.id + '</button>'});
  main.insertAdjacentHTML ("afterEnd", mainContent);
}

function output(jsonObj) {
    console.log(jsonObj);

}
function input(jsonObj){
    document.getElementById('id').value = jsonObj.id;
}
```

And test.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Rest API</title>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<div id="main"></div>
<input id="id" value="" type="text" placeholder="Id">
<script src="/students/res/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

That's what i get in browser: [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9OKs.png)

So, "function output(jsonObj)" works fine, but when I`m trying to pass data from a specific object to "input" (there must be a form in which the data (name,age, etc.) will change) I get this:"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mko6g.png)

Found some information here: [onclick="doSomething([object Object])" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753245/onclick-dosomethingobject-object-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifi). But it does not help much bcoz I can`t hardcode data like this:

```
var params = {a:1,b:2};
```

So what am I doing wrong? (no frameworks should be used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by this:

```
let requestURL = 'list';
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();

let main = document.getElementById ("main");

request.onload = function() {
  const students = request.response;
  students.forEach(student => {
  var  button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = 'Id: ' + student.id;
  main.appendChild(button);
  button.addEventListener("click", function(){
      input(student);
    });
  })
}

function input(jsonObj){
    document.getElementById('id').value = jsonObj.id;
    document.getElementById('name').value = jsonObj.firstName;
    document.getElementById('age').value = jsonObj.age;
}
```

Comment: any recommendations how to do it better?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to do something like:

```
  mainContent += '<button id="edit" onclick="function() {
    input(' + JSON.stringify(student) + ');}">
  Id: ' + student.id + '</button>'});
```

But you really shouldn't be using the onXXX methods at all, as they will get nullified if there is a Content-Security-Policy. You should be using `element.addEventListener`

Comment: I tried as u wrote and I get:"Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name". So I tried "(function() {})()" and "(function() {}())" and get same :"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input". U said to use element.addEventListener, but how can I do it for each 1000+ students with the ability to display a form with the data of a specific student?(I`m new in js)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use like:

```
onclick="myFunction({greeting:'abc'})"
```

Comment: I know that, but I can`t hardcode data, it must be get form [student]