# JavaScript function to get an object literal string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate an object literal string from an object. I know I can myself create a function to do this with something like:

```
//pseudocode
function getOL(object){
  for(var prop in object){
    if(!object.hasOwnProperty(prop)){return;}
    else if (typeof var === object){/*recur*/}
    //case function
    //case string
  }
}
```

However, this method seems pretty grossly inefficient. Even if there isn't a native function, which is what seems like is the case, is there some alternative way to write this that is more efficient than recursively looping over every property of an object and its children?

Comment: If this is just for debugging purposes, then I would suggest that you just get Firebug and use `console.debug()`.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` may work to an extent. It even accepts arguments to control indentation.

Comment: @Travesty3 That was how I got here in the first place, but turned into me just being annoyed that there wasn't a more efficient way to get that string back out. I wonder how FireBug implements that method, though.

Comment: @pimvdb interesting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480393/alternatives-of-json-stringify-in-javascript seems to imply that JSON.stringify() has some inconsistencies. That said, someone also claims that https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js is the basis for modern stringifiy methods, so I'll have a look at how they have gone about this.

Comment: Aside from quite a bit of very interesting javascript quirky-ness, looks like JSON2.js (and preseumably browser JSON.stringify() implementations) is still fundamentally built around looping over the properties and recurring when necessary.

Comment: @MaxPRafferty: What else did you expect? To serialize a [JS object] tree, you will have to iterate its nodes.

Comment: @Bergi sure, which is why that is the immediately obvious solution to the problem. One imagined scenario is that there would be some way to get some sort of structured "variable dump", and then process that string into an object literal, avoiding a lot of unnecessary hasOwnProperty checks and  potential JavaScript object processing wierdness. But I am not aware of any way to do such a thing, or any other alternative possibility i can imagine.